# Oracle NetSuite: How to get internal/external id from currency?

Tags: netsuite

I am a newbie of NetSuite developer.

We have some [Currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKPhM.png) HKD/CAD/EUR/USD/CNY/SGD/GBP/AUD in accounting, and HKD is the base currency.

Now I want to [add USD currency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EPWW.png) to all customer by importing csv, but don't know how to get information of USD currency:

```
    RecordRef ccy = new RecordRef();
    ccy.setType(RecordType.CURRENCY);
    ccy.setInternalId("?"); // Don't know how to get internal id of USD currency
    ccy.setExternalId("?"); // Don't know how to get internal id of USD currency

    CustomerCurrency customerCcy = new CustomerCurrency();
    customerCcy.setCurrency(ccy);
    CustomerCurrencyList customerCcyList = new CustomerCurrencyList();
    customerCcyList.getCurrency().add(customerCcy);
    customer.setCurrencyList(customerCcyList);

    updateCustomer(customer);
```

Please give some advise to me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In you netsuite preferences, you can turn on the option for "Show internal ids."  Once you have that set, the currency view should show you your internal ids.  Alternatively, you can right click and go to developer tools in chrome or firefox and look at the internal ids on the elements.